Error in proof of one-loop exactness of supersymmetric beta function?
I am following David Tong's lectures on SUSY and at some point, in page 157 he proves the one-loop exactness of the beta function for a supersymmetric theory. The problem is that there is a part of the proof which I do not fully comprehend.
I will begin by giving a sketch of the proof: Tong approximates the gauge coupling running to one loop at the begining of page 155 (the equation is unnumbered in the notes)
$$
\dfrac{1}{g^2(\mu)} = \dfrac{1}{g^2_0} - \dfrac{b_o}{(4\pi)^2}\log{\dfrac{\Lambda^2_{UV}}{\mu^2}}, \tag{*}
$$
from which he obtains the RG invariant (up to one loop), below (6.1),
$$
|\Lambda| = \mu \exp\left( -\dfrac{8\pi^2}{b_0 g^2(\mu)} \right).\tag{**}
$$
Based on this, he defines
$$
\tau(\mu) = \dfrac{\theta}{2\pi} + \dfrac{4\pi i}{g^2(\mu)}, \tag{6.2}
$$
and
$$
\Lambda = \mu \exp\left( \dfrac{2\pi i \tau(\mu)}{b_0 } \right). \tag{6.3}
$$
From here, he obtains
$$
\tau(\mu;\Lambda) = \dfrac{b_0}{2\pi i} \log{\dfrac{\Lambda}{\mu}}, \tag{6.4}
$$
which he later Taylor-expands in $\frac{\Lambda}{\mu}$ to account for multi-loop contributions to the beta function, which he concludes to not be perturbative, QED.
But the following problem arises: In order to obtain equation (6.4), Tong has already assumed that the beta function is one-loop exact in equation (*), so, in a sense, we are assuming A to prove that indeed A is true. As an alternative, we could actually have that (6.4)'s correct form is
$$
\tau(\mu;\Lambda) = \dfrac{b_0 + b_1}{2\pi i} \log{\dfrac{\Lambda}{\mu}}, \tag{6.4'}
$$
without spoiling the part where we say that there are no further perturbative contributions.
My question is, how do we justify (6.4) without already approximating one-loop exactness in (1)? How do we armour-plate this argument against having alternatives like (6.4')?

I don't think Tong's notes are meant to be a rigorous proof, so you might want to look at some of the literature. I'm also not an expert on SUSY. But at least one semi-plausibility argument is that I think higher looper corrections tend to involve higher powers of $\log$ (like a two loop correction would usually involve a $\log^2$ term).
